# Adding data in jsp table left to right from java

Tags: java, html, jsp, html-table

Normally a table fills that way :

| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

I want to fill a table in my jsp like this :

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | _ | _ | _ |

(Underscore are actually empty cells)

I have my data from my java code in a variable and I use a **Foreach** . I don't know how many elements I will have in list. It can go from 1 to 250. I want rows of 6 column maximum. When the six column are filled, it must change to a new row.

This is my actual code :

```
<TABLE width="100%" class="table">
        <bean:define id="listResult" name="formePage" property="sectionReponse.listResult"/>
        <c:forEach items="${listResult}" var="resultat">
            <tr>        
                <c:when test="${resultat.codGropIntv == 'x'}">
                    <td class="atblCell">
                        <c:out value='${resultat.nomFichier}' /></a>
                    </td>
                </c:when>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

P.S. I would like to do this without changing the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it and I will share it in case someone else encontered the same problem.

```
<TABLE width="100%" class="table">
    <bean:define id="listResult" name="formePage" property="sectionReponse.listResult"/>
    <fmt:formatNumber var="i" value="0"/>
    <c:forEach items="${listResult}" var="resultat">
        <c:if test="${i == 0}">
            <tr>
        </c:if>        
        <td class="atblCell">
            <c:out value='${resultat.nomFichier}' /></a>
        </td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${i == 6}">
                <fmt:formatNumber var="i" value="0"/>
                </tr>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <fmt:formatNumber var="i" value="${i + 1}"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose> 
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```